# Linux sed replace a string - Can someone explain this error?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I have 1 file and hope use sed to replace the string.

a.txt

```
#define 1
#define 2
```

b.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin
export PATH

MODEL_NAME='123 %s abc 3.0 %d <<456: %s>>'
sed -i 's/#define 1/#define 1 \"'${MODEL_NAME}'\"/g' 1.txt
```

My expect result in 1.txt:

```
#define 1 "123 %s abc 3.0 %d <<456: %s>>"
#define 2
```

But I got the error message from console:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 27: unterminated `s' command
```

Could someone help explain the condition for this? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using single quotes around your `sed` command, the shell variable `${MODEL_NAME}` never gets expanded. Try:

```
sed -i "s/#define 1/#define 1 \"${MODEL_NAME}\"/g" 1.txt
```